# Having trouble with a one dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

My assignment asks:

Design a program that will simulate how theater seats may fill as people walk into the theater.  The program should maximize the distance between each person by trying to find a seat in the middle of the longest sequence of unoccupied seats. The program should ask the user for the amount of seats and then print out diagrams (one diagram per line) each time a new person occupies a seat.

So far I have:

```
{
    //...
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of seats: ");
    int seatNumber = input.nextInt();

    boolean[] seatPosition = new boolean[seatNumber];
    String result = "";

    for(int n = 0; n < seatNumber; n++){
        for(int i = 0; i < seatNumber; i++){
            if(seatPosition[i] == false){
                result += "_" + " ";
            }else{
                result += "X" + " ";
            }
        }
        seatPosition[calculation(seatPosition)] = true;
        result += "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}

public static int calculation(boolean[] values){
    int position = 0;
    int seatNumber = 0;
    int largestCount = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        if(values[seatNumber] == false){
            while(values[seatNumber] == true){
                count++;
                seatNumber++;
            }
        }
        if(count > largestCount){
            position = seatNumber;
        }   
    position = position + largestCount / 2 ;
    }

    return position;
}
```

The output for ten seats is:

```
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
_ _ _ _ _ X _ _ _ _
_ _ X _ _ X _ _ _ _
_ _ X _ _ X _ _ X _
_ X X _ _ X _ _ X _
_ X X _ X X _ _ X _
_ X X _ X X _ X X _
X X X _ X X _ X X _
X X X X X X _ X X _
X X X X X X X X X _
X X X X X X X X X X
```

I'm lost on how to compare the length of the empty seats and how I would return what the middle seat is of the longest sequence of unoccupied seats. The output has 11 rows because I'm suppose to display the seats before they are occupied and each time a new seat gets occupied. Sorry if I'm not very specific this is the first time asking a question on this site.

Comment: so what's your specific problem? throwing out an assignment and saying that "I don't know how to do it" is not how stackoverflow works.  The logic should not be difficult though

Comment: Could you explain what is the problem with that code ? Is it running, did you have an output ? How is it failing / crashing ?

Comment: Just done it, quite funny. Just for info, your calculation declare 6 `int` but only use 2 and return one without touching it. You might start with that ;) I have done it with 3 variable (probably not the best).

Comment: I changed the code inside of the method but it only fills in the first seat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a variable that represents a location on the row. Let that position be the starting position of the line of unoccupied seats. Find that position, then calculate exactly how long it is until the next occupied seat, divide that by two, then add that to the starting seat. Pseudo code for the algorithm

```
int position
int seat#
int largest count
int count
repeat seat# times
    if seat# isn't occupied
        count number of seats until the next seat occupied.
    if count > largest count
        position = seat#
position = position + largest count / 2
```

Comment: It does not answer the question. And most importantly that assignment is made to be unrealistic and contains one row only: You cannot have a proper (or at least clear) definition of "sequence" if you are considering multiple rows.

Comment: And his output contains more than one row.

Comment: there is only 1 row: It is simply showing how that row is filled by 10 persons

Comment: ... I'm a moron XD

Comment: take it easy.  It took me some time to figure that out either :P  OP is not asking the question right....

Comment: I tried cycling through the program and it works but I just don't know how to find the middle of the longest sequence of unoccupied seats. The program is suppose to display each time a new person seats down which is why there are multiple rows in the output.

Comment: Nice pseudo-code.  Should be enough for OP.  Though you may want to take a second though for the logic, coz what you are doing is in complexity O(n^2) and there are ways to make it O(n)  :)

Comment: @AdrianShum, O(n^2) ? With only a `repeat seat# times` ?

Comment: but for each seat you are doing *"count number of seats until the next seat occupied"*

Comment: @AdrianShum How, I had read that like an incremented variable (count number of seat) ... You are right.